# discord.py how to get id of an member that just joined the vc

Tags: python, events, discord, bots

I mean title says everything.

how can I get id from this "member" command? Im trying to send a message to a channel when specific person joins vc. but idk how to get id of a person that joined vc.
I read some documents about this and all of them like message.author.id or smth. im new at this. consider explaining :)

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):

if not before.channel and after.channel:
    channel = client.get_channel("channel id here")
    await channel.send('hello')

elif before.channel and not after.channel:
    channel = client.get_channel("channelk id here")
    await channel.send('bye')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `member` here is an instance of `discord.Member`, you can use the `id` attribute of that to access there id, like `member.id`, https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/api.html#discord.Member.id, this returns an int of there id